# Why is this console log posting "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined, declaration

i made an array that gets a variable to specify the value i want to display

```
var antallSporsmal= 0;
var fasit = new Array();
fasit[1,3,1,2,3];
console.log(fasit[antallSporsmal]);
```

Comment: The statement `fasit[1,3,1,2,3];` does absolutely nothing.

Comment: You should use `var fasit = [1,3,1,2,3];` and remove the `fasit[1,3,1,2,3];` line

Comment: This is why people need to run linters in their IDE. jshint, jslint, eslint, etc. JSHint would have 8 warning with those 4 lines of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is goes:

Your code:

```
var antallSporsmal= 0;
var fasit = new Array();
fasit[1,3,1,2,3];
console.log(fasit[antallSporsmal]);
```

Code you should use:

```
var fasit =[1,3,1,2,3];
var antallSporsmal= 0;
console.log(fasit[antallSporsmal]);
```

Answer (score 2):

In your line :

```
fasit[1,3,1,2,3];
```

You are not initializing your array, this does nothing. so `fasit` will be always empty, that's why `fasit[0]` will be `undefined`.

You need to change it:

```
fasit = [1,3,1,2,3];
```

Answer (score 2):

Because your `fasit` array is empty. You're effectively calling `fasit[0]` but it doesn't exist due to the empty array.

If you want to add the `1,3,1,2,3` numbers to the array, might wanna change `fasit[1,3,1,2,3];` to `fasit.push(1,3,1,2,3);`

Or just assign a new array to the `fasit` variable like this: `fasit = [1,3,1,2,3];`

Answer (score 0):

Statement `fasit[1,3,1,2,3];` - doing nothing.

```
var antallSporsmal= 0;
var fasit = [1,3,1,2,3];
console.log(fasit[antallSporsmal]); // output 1
```

as example.

Also `new Array()` takes as an argument a number and creates an array with a given length.

If need to add some element to array, use `arr.push()`.

Answer (score 0):

> Did you mean this

```
var antallSporsmal= 0;
var fasit = [1,3,1,2,3];
console.log(fasit[antallSporsmal]);
```

> You can also use push

```
var fasit=new Array();
fasit.push(1,3,1,2,4);
console.log(fasit[0]);
```